# Setting CSP (Frame Ancestors) in Single Page App

Tags: javascript, webpack, single-page-application, webpack-dev-server, svelte

How do I set a Frame Ancestors CSP in a single page app using Webpack bundler? I know frame ancestors can't be set using a `<meta>` tag in my HTML.

I've tried attaching the `Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self'` in the webpack-dev-server headers option but it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the directive frame-src.

```
frame-src 'self' https://www.youtube.com/
```